# Conditional sum in R including string responses from other column

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements

I'd like to find the total # of respondents that drive Hondas and also are bankers from the following dataset CarPurchases:

| Type | EmployHistory |
| --- | --- |
| Honda | Banker, Analyst, Student |
| Toyota | Government, Banker |
| Honda | Banker |
| Hyundai | Student |

Appreciate any insight, thank you.

Comment: Similar to below answer you may try - `sum(grepl('Banker', df$EmployHistory) & df$Type == 'Honda')`

Answer (score 0):

try `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
dt <- CarPurchases |> as.data.table() ## convert to table
dt[Type == 'Honda' & grepl("Banker", x = EmployHistory) ,.N,]
```

Comment: Thank you both, they both worked beautifully!